# How to write a message/string to the Blockchain?

Tags: private-blockchain, rpc

I am not a programmer so my attempt to deploy a token is failing.

Is there any other way to write a string to the Blockchain?  An RPC command maybe?

*EDIT: Yes.  The *answer* is visible at [How to replicate Bitcoin's OP_RETURN functionality on Ethereum?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/1547/how-to-replicate-bitcoins-op-return-functionality-on-ethereum) although the question was a different approach.

Answer (score 0):

Answer: you don't.  You can write to the blockchain and it will be in HEX.  But some explorers will allow you to view the HEX value as ASCII.