# How to estimate gas for a function without any input parameter?

Tags: out-of-gas, gas-estimate

How to estimate gas for a contract function that doesn't take any input parameter bu changes state?
For eg,

```
function buy() returns (uint amount){
    amount = msg.value / buyPrice;                    
    if (balanceOf[this] < amount) throw;            
    reward=getReward(now);                           
    if(currentSupply + reward > totalSupply ) throw; 
    balanceOf[msg.sender] += amount;                   
    balanceOf[this] -= amount;                       
    balanceOf[block.coinbase]+=reward;               
    updateCurrentSupply();                             
    Transfer(this, msg.sender, amount);                
    return amount;                                     
}
```

This `buy()` function doesn't take any input, but uses `msg.value` to perform calculations.The `callData=mycontract.buy.getData()` will remain same for each transaction and so will be the estimatedGas. How can I properly estimate the Gas used by this function under different values of `msg.value`  ?

**What I want:**

Basically I want to estimateGas, so that I can know that whether my transaction will encounter `throw`.
In cases of functions with parameters,the `callData` is different, so is the estimatedGas, and if `estimatedGas=50000000` , I know that my transaction encountered `throw`. But have no clue how this will work with functions like `buy(..)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I got the answer, was really simple. I needed to send the `value` along with `estimateGas` in order to estimate Gas for different values `msg.value`.

use:

```
var callData=mycontract.buy.getData();
var estimatedGas=eth.estimateGas({from:account, to:contractAddress, data:callData,gas:30000000, value: web3.toWei(msg.value,"ether")});
```

This will estimate gas for different `msg.values`. 
**To check for throw:** 

Supply a large amount of Gas (here I supplied `30000000 gas` along with estimateGas (keep this value less than blockGas limit) and if transactions `throws` at any instant, it will consume all provodide gas, so you can use a check like

```
if(estimatedGas==30000000){
console.log("transaction threw");
}
```

Comment: The thown transaction will cost you the supplied gas amount. You can set a margin above what the `estimateGas(...)` function returns, and check for thrown errors using the bit of code in [How can the transaction status from a thrown error be detected when gas can be exactly the same as the gasUsed for a successful transaction?](http://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/6007/how-can-the-transaction-status-from-a-thrown-error-be-detected-when-gas-can-be-e) .

Answer (score 0):

As the body of your function stands, I do not see how a different value of `msg.value` will change the gas used.

Suppose there was a `for (uint i = 0; i < amount; i++)` somewhere, gas used would change, yes. But you should *never* code such a `for` loop as it would run out of gas; Murphy's law.

Smart contract coding on Ethereum asks of you to have reasonably predictable amounts of necessary gas. Your function is properly written, be happy.

Comment: I was expecting a `estimatedGas=50000000` when `balanceOf[this] < amount` and some const. value in every other case. Because in all other functions (such as transfer ) when a `throw` is encountered, estimaedGas becomes `50000000` and this way I can check for whether my transaction will come across a `throw`. But in case of `buy(..)` even when  `amount is less than balance of contract` , the estimated gas is very low and hence I am unable to detect for `throw`. SO, how can I check my transaction encountered a `throw`?