# How to estimate the cost to call a Smart Contract method?

Tags: contract-development, blockchain, contract-invocation, abi, gas-estimate

After succesfully deployed this Smart Contract on Ethereum testnet

```
https://testnet.etherscan.io/address/0x27c042342C9ba937214117e11A4970A6145034cB
```

is it possible to calculate how much gas is going to take to invoke a given method of the Smart Contract?

Reading [How to estimate gas for a function without any input parameter?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/8768/how-to-estimate-gas-for-a-function-without-any-input-parameter) and [How much does it cost to use a contract?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/799/how-much-does-it-cost-to-use-a-contract) and [What are the limitations to estimateGas and when would its estimate be considerably wrong?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/266/what-are-the-limitations-to-estimategas-and-when-would-its-estimate-be-considera) didn't help me as expected...

This is how to instantiate the Smart Contract on geth console command line:

```
// creation of contract object
var aContract = web3.eth.contract([ { "constant": true, "inputs": [], "name": "queryNumEscrows", "outputs": [ { "name": "", "type": "uint256", "value": "0" } ], "type": "function" }, { "constant": true, "inputs": [ { "name": "escrowId", "type": "uint256" } ], "name": "queryStatus", "outputs": [ { "name": "status", "type": "uint256", "value": "0" } ], "type": "function" }, { "constant": false, "inputs": [ { "name": "seller", "type": "address" }, { "name": "thirdParty", "type": "address" } ], "name": "start1", "outputs": [ { "name": "escrowId", "type": "uint256" } ], "type": "function" }, { "constant": false, "inputs": [ { "name": "escrowId", "type": "uint256" } ], "name": "revoke", "outputs": [ { "name": "amount", "type": "uint256" } ], "type": "function" }, { "constant": false, "inputs": [ { "name": "escrowId", "type": "uint256" } ], "name": "release", "outputs": [ { "name": "amount", "type": "uint256" } ], "type": "function" }, { "constant": false, "inputs": [ { "name": "seller", "type": "address" }, { "name": "thirdParty", "type": "address" } ], "name": "start", "outputs": [ { "name": "", "type": "uint256" } ], "type": "function" }, { "constant": false, "inputs": [], "name": "kill", "outputs": [], "type": "function" } ]);

// initiate contract for an address
var sc = aContract.at('0x27c042342C9ba937214117e11A4970A6145034cB');

// view code
eth.getCode(sc.address);
```

Now, I want to send this transaction to the Smart Contract, but I would like to previously know how much gas is it going to take:

```
sc.start.sendTransaction("0x90e8682b63d7922a3e942d4bbd4c88095634a17b", "0x47978a69f410d0f61850c92acdb0d4c464d70937", {from:"0x3b877e80b5c0b29d88f3768ed4292b35fdd93a9d", value:"0x3b9aca00"});
```

to avoid this message:

```
"Warning! Error encountered during contract execution [Out of gas]".
```

I guess the following json-rpc method should be used:

```
https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/JSON-RPC#eth_estimategas
```

I have read at docs that:

```
When calling SCs => data: DATA - (optional) Hash of the method signature and encoded parameters.
```

But don't get how to encode method name, parameters and ABI in data field. Any idea?

Or is there any other way round to tackle this issue?

Thx.

Comment: There is a worked example at http://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/7557/syntax-for-calling-contract-state-changing-methods. Then search this site for ABI to work out the encoding.

Comment: Thx, that's a good starting point...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The documentation is skimpy on details and it took me forever to figure out the correct way with the help of your links, anyways, here is what works for me:

Tested on Geth : 1.6.7 -stable , web3.js :0.20.2  Parity/v1.7.2 & Kovan testnet.

I'll be using the minimal token as example :

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.0;

contract minimalToken {

     mapping (address => uint256) public balanceOf;

    function minimalToken(uint256 initialSupply) {
        balanceOf[msg.sender] = initialSupply;
    }

    function transfer(address _to, uint256 _value) {
        require(balanceOf[msg.sender] >= _value);
        require(balanceOf[_to] + _value >= balanceOf[_to]);
        balanceOf[msg.sender] -= _value;
        balanceOf[_to] += _value;
    }
}
```

I'll be focusing on the transfer method which takes 2 arguments,( address, amount) to transfer:

```
    var contract = web3.eth.contract(contractABI).at("0x8caaa1f263ff14d0276ff1a1a6ed15c51159d6e0");
    var receiverAddress = '0x00Ce6C92856A657979E7728005DBc9acD002Eb09';
    var callData = contract.transfer.getData(receiverAddress, 2000);

    var gasEstimate = web3.eth.estimateGas({
        from: web3.eth.coinbase,
        to: "0x8caaa1f263ff14d0276ff1a1a6ed15c51159d6e0",
        data: callData
    });

    var gasPrice = web3.eth.gasPrice;

    console.log('gas Price: ' + gasPrice);
    console.log('Estimated Transaction gas: ' + gasEstimate);

// gas Price: 21000000000
// Estimated Transaction gas: 34207
```

One thing that Threw me off, was that I kept on getting transaction errors due to me not including the **from:** field on the transaction.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to know this *in development*, you can get a good estimate by using [testrpc](https://github.com/ethereumjs/testrpc) to simulate the blockchain. After sending a transaction, it will tell you the gas usage in the terminal.

If you are experiencing out-of-gas errors, you may also consider using testrpc (or browser-solidity) to determine it actually *is* an out-of-gas error. Other errors (throws, bad array lookups, etc) will appear as OOGs to most nodes. testrpc and browser-solidity will tell you if it's something else.