# Contract transaction: Gas estimated doesn't fit gas used

Tags: contract-development, blockchain, gas, contract-invocation, gas-estimate

After finding out how to estimate contract tx fees thx to [How to estimate the cost to call a Smart Contract method?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/9249/how-to-estimate-the-cost-to-call-a-smart-contract-method) and [Syntax for calling contract state changing methods](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/7557/syntax-for-calling-contract-state-changing-methods) I tried to use all that knowledge and implement my own contract transaction with previous gas estimation, but they differ quite a lot. **Gas estimated is 27,348 meanwhile Gas consumed is 181,080**. So, what is wrong? Is this gas estimation process well done when dealing with smart contracts?

This is the data I used to estimate the gas for the endpoint: **"start(address, address)"** in a Smart Contract with address **0x27c042342C9ba937214117e11A4970A6145034cB**

```
web3_sha3(endpoint) = 0xaa6d19c0b1d22f6983033c255695177ad1db0a0aad0435b6f6a367b48d4b37f4 
arguments = "0xa7e3c7c227c72a60e5a2f9912448fb1c21078769, 0xf28dafbfeb41bf32869c9d498da0d651d0206ed4" 
strhex(arguments) = 0x3078613765336337633232376337326136306535613266393931323434386662316332313037383736392c20307866323864616662666562343162663332383639633964343938646130643635316430323036656434 
data = 0xaa6d19c03078613765336337633232376337326136306535613266393931323434386662316332313037383736392c20307866323864616662666562343162663332383639633964343938646130643635316430323036656434
```

yielding a Gas estimation of: 27,348

On the other hand, following tx is performed:

```
sc.start.sendTransaction("0xa7e3c7c227c72a60e5a2f9912448fb1c21078769", "0x47978a69f410d0f61850c92acdb0d4c464d70937", {from:"0x3b877e80b5c0b29d88f3768ed4292b35fdd93a9d", value:"0x55ae82600", gas:1000000});

txHash: 0xbad5639d7f02cfb1658580eb8cab5f950d379ee8197f423178391dc70701459f
```

and once the tx has been mined this is the resulting gas values:

```
Gas: 1,000,000
Gas Used By Transaction: 181,080
```

So, why estimated gas is so off? Thx in advance!

Comment: Different code paths taken during the estimate and the one that gets mined?  It also seems the 2nd argument in the sendTransaction is different from the one provided in the estimate.  http://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/266/what-are-the-limitations-to-estimategas-and-when-would-its-estimate-be-considera

Answer (score 1):

I have found something, maybe it could help others...

Signature to hash **is NOT** "start(address, address)" but instead "start(address,address)". This white space changes everything.

I've also found very valuable info about passing parameters to contracts on https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/Ethereum-Contract-ABI#examples

Answer (score 0):

Now, it works like a charm!

```
endpoint = "start(address,address)" 
web3_sha3(endpoint) = 0x3ccfe887556b4c598501287bcd4528f0b8830f303e150d3b4c3ac9831b7989a8 
arguments = Array (
    [sellerAddress] => Array
        (
            [type] => address
            [value] => 0xa7e3c7c227c72a60e5a2f9912448fb1c21078769
        )

    [thirdPartyAddress] => Array
        (
            [type] => address
            [value] => 0xf28dafbfeb41bf32869c9d498da0d651d0206ed4
        )
)
data = 0x3ccfe887000000000000000000000000a7e3c7c227c72a60e5a2f9912448fb1c21078769000000000000000000000000f28dafbfeb41bf32869c9d498da0d651d0206ed4
```

gasEstimated = 181,080

*Arguments must be encoded one after the other, each one 32-bytes 0-left-padded, so each one uses 64 hex characters to be represented.*