# Transaction not going through in Mist 0.8.6

Tags: mist

I have update Mist-wallet to latest [0.8.6 version](https://github.com/ethereum/mist/releases/tag/v0.8.6) and I was trying to execute a contract on my Test-network before working on Public net with this version. When I execute contract with fee suggested by Mist, it says

> It seems your transaction will fail. If you submit it, it may consume all the gas you send.

I even provided the max available fee in Mist i.e `1.0541272 ether`, And on confirmation page I see provide max fee as `0.02550988 ether (121000 gas)`. But still getting hit by same error message on confirmation page.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is normally an error detected by the [`eth.estimateGas(...)`](https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/JavaScript-API#web3ethestimategas) function call, where this call returns back a result that `gasUsed==gas` as you have found in your answer to [How to estimate gas for a function without any input parameter?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/a/8786/1268).

You can see the Mist error message at [mist.en.i18n.json#L193](https://github.com/ethereum/mist/blob/1e8577383fd3c58b067f2675d7e26006043407d8/interface/i18n/mist.en.i18n.json#L193):

```
"estimatedGasError": "It seems this transaction will fail. If you submit it, it may consume all the gas you send.",
```

And this `estimatedGasError` error message is displayed by the code at [sendTransactionConfirmation.html#L56-L66](https://github.com/ethereum/mist/blob/c3ae7606ed441f2aad11ed4542fb7ced47ede00e/interface/client/templates/popupWindows/sendTransactionConfirmation.html#L56-L66):

```
{{#if transactionInvalid}}
    <p class="info dapp-error"> {{{i18n "mist.popupWindows.sendTransactionConfirmation.estimatedGasError"}}} </p>
{{else}}
...
{{/if}}
```

The `transactionInvalid` status is computed by the code at [sendTransactionConfirmation.js#L259-L263](https://github.com/ethereum/mist/blob/c3ae7606ed441f2aad11ed4542fb7ced47ede00e/interface/client/templates/popupWindows/sendTransactionConfirmation.js#L259-L263):

```
'transactionInvalid': function() {
    return TemplateVar.get('estimatedGas') == 'invalid' 
            || TemplateVar.get('estimatedGas') == 0
            || typeof TemplateVar.get('estimatedGas') == 'undefined';
}
```

You may want to check your smart contract code to work out why the an error is being thrown.

Comment: Thanks for elaborated answer, but I don't think there is any issue with my contract code. I have deployed same contract code on previous versions of Mist including 0.8.5. So why this version won't let me execute my contract if contract code is fine.

Comment: I have 3 versions of Mist, 0.8.1, 0.8.5 and latest 0.8.6. My contract code gets deployed on` v 0.8.`  but gives same error message on `v 0.8.5` and   `v 0.8.6`. There is no syntax error obviously otherwise compiler would have detected it, so what is there is latest versions that is preventing my contract from deployment.One more thing, I am pretty sure I deployed same code on v0.8.5 3 days ago and it worked fine. But now I am getting hit by same error in this version too. Quite confused.

Comment: Got the issue, was a typo. The account from which transaction was being send in latest version was different from main account, so was throwing error. I updated the `from` while deploying contract to main address and worked fine.