# "Intrinsic gas too low" error when deploying the crypto recipe from Ethereum.org

Tags: mist, gas, tokens

Using the latest version of Mist on Mac OSX, I'm simply trying to deploy the crypto coin recipe straight from the Ethereum website and deploy on the Mist test net.

The code compiles with no errors before deployment, but halts with an "Intrinsic gas too low" error, despite my making no amendments to the code example.

Based on other questions on the same topic, this is about the intrinsic being set too low - but that value is hard coded and cannot be changed in the UI. Another answer given on the forum suggests inserting "Payable" in the contract's functions, after the arguments. Alas, this did not allow me to deploy.

I'm wondering if this is something i'm missing from the tutorial, or a problem with my wallet, or a bug in the code that is not immediately obvious.

https://www.ethereum.org/token

Comment: Related: [Mist: What does “intrinsic gas too low” mean?](http://ethereum.stackexchange.com/q/1570/87)

Answer (score 1):

The code doesn't seem to have any problem. I have tried deploying the code and it works fab. 
The one reason may be that the account from which you are trying to deploy the contract doesn't have sufficient ethers. Please verify this.

> but that value is hard coded on the mist wallet and cannot be changed
>   in the UI.

No, the value is not hard coded. You can change the fee provided. Just under the contract deployment section- you can see, there is a select fee option. You can increase the gas provided for deploying your contract by moving the `SELECT FEE` slider towards `FASTER` end.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, firstly I confirm I have enough ether. I think the UI would throw an 'insufficient funds in main account' error in that situation..

As far as the fee slider, yes that does amend the Gas Price, but the:

Estimated fee consumption   0.01513492 ether (756,746 gas)
Provide maximum fee   0.00306002 ether (153,001 gas)

remain locked out, and perhaps this is where the problem is. 

I think it's really odd that my UI, the latest version, with no amendments to the code at all, is throwing an error that you (and presumably the rest of the world!) are not seeing.

Comment: It goes without saying, but I'm not getting this contract to deploy wherever the slider is set. "Intrinsic gas" is a hard coded value and I dont think the transaction fee is related to the problem. I've amended my question to be more clear.

Comment: It's quite odd that the values of `Estimated Fee Consumption` is locked out and doesn't change with `Select Fee` slider. Let me upgrade my wallet to v0.8.9 and I'll try to replicate the issue. This may be an issue with latest etherum wallet, coz it works fab with v0.8.6.

Comment: If you see clearly, with the change in `Select Fee` slider your **gas price changes**. Although the gas supplied remains locked but due to change in gas price, the fee you provide for your transaction varies. (estimated fee = gas*gas price). SO there is no issue with ethereum-wallet

Comment: Now coming to your main question can you send me result of command ` eth.getBalance(eth.coinbase)`?